# Pytorch: best practice to save big list of tensors?

Tags: pytorch

I use tensors to do transformation then I save it in a list. Later, I will make it a dataset using `Dataset`, then finally `DataLoader` to train my model. To do it, I can simply use:

```
l = [tensor1, tensor2, tensor3,...]
dataset = Dataset.TensorDataset(l)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset)
```

I wonder what is the best practice doing so, to avoid RAM overflow if the size of `l` grows? Can something like `Iterator` avoid it?

Comment: Do you know the logic behind each element, eg. can you generate the data with each `__getitem__` call? If so, you can exchange the memory overhead to a bit of computing. There are few reasons to think of RAM use before it really comes a problem.

Comment: I get each element from another `DataLoader`, do some transformations, then the final result is what I want to save it to a list. I plan to save all the tensors returned from the DataLoader in the list. The data I am using is CIFAR-100, but soon it will grow to ImageNet.

Comment: I would not create a new dataset in this case. Use the original dataloader and do transformations batches received from that loader or inherit that loader and add your own transformations to it.

Comment: That's what I am doing, but now I want to save the whole transformed tensors until the end, then train the model, instead of training every step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save tensors

```
for idx, tensor in enumerate(dataloader0):
    torch.save(tensor, f"{my_folder}/tensor{idx}.pt")
```

Create dataset

```
class FolderDataset(Dataset):
   def __init__(self, folder):
       self.files = os.listdir(folder)
       self.folder = folder
   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.files)
   def __getitem__(self, idx):
       return torch.load(f"{self.folder}/{self.files[idx]}")
```

And then you can implement your own dataloader. If you can't hold the whole dataset in memory, some file system loading is required.